# Can Nero InfoTool work with Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, nero

I use Virtualbox 4.3.6. The guest and the host are both Windows 7 x64 SP1 Ultimate. I tried to use [Nero InfoTool 11](http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html) to analyze one of my CDs but it always get stuck at the following screen:

[image]

I tried with a DVD and I have the same issue. The task manager can't manage to kill it, and Windows 7 won't even reboot: I have to power off the machine each time.

Nero InfoTool works fine outside the virtual machine.

Can Nero InfoTool work with Virtualbox?

Comment: Based on what you describe, no, you can't.  The program likely is sending hardware command the virtual hardware is unaware of

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: Nero InfoTool currently does not work with Virtualbox.